# How can I add a driver to DBeaver to connect to a database?

Tags: postgresql, driver, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database but am getting an error telling me the connection attempt has failed even though my login details are correct. Below is the error that appears
[image]

I have downloaded the .jar file and added the file to the library section of the driver information however I am still not having any luck.

I tried the same thing with the SQLite example database that is created when you first open DBeaver but run into the same issue.

Any help?